# Where to find Windows Internet Explorer Platform APIs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create Console App which uses [Internet Explorer Object as here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx).

I am having a hard time finding and downloading the DLLs for it.

Any clue is well appreciated.

Mehdi

Comment: So you want to use the code from a GUI app for a console application?  But to answer your question, I've used COM objects rather than just the DLLs in the past, but then that was a GUI app I was writing.

Comment: It is already on your machine, never download DLLs.  Using references from the COM tab isn't for everybody, do use WebBrowser instead.

Comment: If you use the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser you have to cast to mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 to see what's there.  NOTE : there are many other interfaces that expose other parts of the document.  But if you use System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser many of those interfaces are there by default.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't find WebBrowser. How do you think I can find it? I searched the COM and .Net tabs. None found!!! :-(

Comment: @JohnPeters can't find the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser in add references. I am windows 8.1 user. Please let me know if any comments. Seems as if I need to install a package or component.